# Android UI automation using TestLink and Jenkins integration

Tags: java, android, junit, jenkins, testlink

This is turning out to be a somewhat complex integration. We have a Jenkins and TestLink server. Jenkins has a TestLink plugin which allows the use of JUnit, TAP, and TestNG to update testplans on TestLink with a pass/fail.

We're at the point where Jenkins can see and "complete" tests (I use that term lightly as no tests are really run). We also have Android UI automation that can be run nightly which uses androids provided UI Automater. This goes through a series of tests which we output test results into logcat that we record.

The goal would be to get the Android UI tests to update test cases in testlink. Unfortunately, it sounds like TestLink needs a JUnit class to run in order to update the testplans.

Has anyone had experience completing this? In any case I will update this post with information on progress.

Comment: _Random shot_: Run uiautomator tests before, write a result-file in JUnit-format on the device/emulator, pull that file, skip execution in TestLink and directly use JUnit class name to get the results.